# SVG Symbols and Use

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG imported into my document which contains a number of symbols. My SVG is then `use`d like so when I need it:

```
  <div class="sidebar-icon__icon">
    <svg><use xlink:href="#svg-box" /></svg>
  </div>
```

This is great and I add some styles like below:

```
  .sidebar-icon__icon
    width: 30%
    margin-right: 10%
    float: left
    position: relative

    svg
      display: block
      width: 100%
      height: 100%
```

This makes the SVG show up nicely but the SVG element is really tall with the graphic vertically centered. Like so:

[image]

I can get the icon to position at the top of this area by adding `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"` to the `symbol` definition but this doesn't make any difference to the height of the SVG area itself.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can solve it.

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the complete SVG and HTML & CSS in a JSfiddle demo.

Comment: posting your fiddle might help others to inspect

Comment: Ok, Check this: http://codepen.io/rctneil/pen/wBbZZw  Why aren't the `<svg>` and `<use>` elements the same size?

Comment: You are only referencing a single element from another SVG.  The size of that other SVG has no effect on the one with the `<use>`.  It sounds like you may be imagining that SVGs have automatic layout like HTML does. Ie. that the SVG will automatically get a size from the contents of the symbol/icon.  It doesn't.  That is not how SVG works.

Comment: Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEzNjE

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the browser can't determine what height to make the SVG, so it is defaulting to the "intrinsic" height of 150px.

The width of a `<div>` is normally 100% of the parent width and the height is determined by its contents.

However in this case, you have specified a width for the `<div>` (30%) but have left the height unspecified.  In addition to that, you have given the `<svg>` no official width or height.  For SVGs these default to 100%.  So in the case of the width, the SVG will be given a width of 100% of the (30%-width) div.  However, the height of the div is indeterminate.  In these situations, browsers have an "intrinsic" width and height that they fall back on.  For width, this is 300px. For height it is 150px.  That 150px is what is being used in your case.

The solution is to give either the `<div>` or the `<svg>` a specific size.  Or put them inside another parent element that has a fixed size.

Comment: Or provide a viewBox which would give them an intrinsic ratio. UAs can then determine the height from the ratio and the width.

Comment: They have a view box already though. This is what is confusing me why the height will not shrink to fit!

Comment: Your symbol SVG might have a viewBox, but that is immaterial, because it is not the SVG that is in your `<div>`..

Comment: @PaulLeBeau If I swap the SVG out for a PNG version of the same thing then the PNG works fine. The width is 100% and the height is figured out in aspect to the width so it's all fine. I understand your points but can't see what is making the SVG act differently to a PNG. I have the preserveAspectRatio attribute set to `xMinYMin meet` so that forces the SVG to be in correct aspect.

Comment: The difference is that the PNG has an natural width and height (and thus aspect ratio).  It's specified in the file itself. The SVG does not because you have not specified one.  I have explained the reason.  What height do you think the SVG should be?